# How to desirialize the http web response

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, httpwebresponse, javascriptserializer

I have used the google API for the getting distance between two area in my **asp.net** application.

which give the result as fallow

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Dhantoli, Nagpur, Maharashtra, India" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Khamla, Nagpur, Maharashtra, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "4.2 km",
                  "value" : 4214
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "8 mins",
                  "value" : 467
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I have collect it in string and try to get the distance text(which is i needed)

for that i have tried the fallowing code it does not working

```
DistanceMatrix data = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DistanceMatrix>(dataString);
```

dataString is the result from API

```
public class DistanceMatrix {
    public string destination_addresses { get; set; }
    public string origin_addresses { get; set; }
    public Element rows { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
public class Element {
    public Data distance { get; set; }
    public Data duration { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
public class Data {
   public string text { get; set; }
   public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me to get the distance text from the API result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using json method use the XML api of google distance matrix api.

Which return the xml response collect it in string and parse it as fallow.

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(dataString);
if (xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("status")[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText == "OK")
{
     XmlNodeList distance = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to do it with JSON (which is entirely possible). Perhaps you should edit the question so that it is about XML?